# Scala/Slick: using inheritance and mixins to reduce boilerplate

Tags: scala, inheritance, playframework, slick, mixins

I'm scala/play/slick newbie so please don't be too mad if I ask dumb question.

Here goes the question.
I have several slick table definitions, here is one of them:

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.db.NamedDatabase
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.Future

case class User(id: Int, login: String, password: String) extends Identifiable

class UserDAO @Inject()(@NamedDatabase protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  private val users = TableQuery[UsersTable]

  def all(): Future[Seq[User]] = db.run(users.result)
  def insert(dog: User): Future[Unit] = db.run(users += dog).map { _ => () }
  def delete(id: Int): Future[Int] = db.run(users.filter(_.id === id).delete)


  private class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USER") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def email = column[String]("email")
    def password = column[String]("password")
    def * = (id, email, password) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }
}
```

Imagine I have much more tables which have `def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)` to eliminate this I need to write something like:

```
trait Identifiable {
  this: Table[_] =>
  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
}
```

But how do I import Table here in a database agnostic manner? Moreover there is more room for enhancements: all DAO objects providing access to Identifiable Tables can be inherited from a common abstract class containing `all`, `insert`, `find` and `delete` methods. Something like (was unable to compile it):

```
abstract class BaseDAO[E <: Identifiable] extends DAO[E] with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._
  private val entities = TableQuery[BaseTable]

  def all(): Future[Seq[E]] = db.run(entities.result)
  def insert(entity: E): Future[Unit] = db.run(entities += entity).map { _ => () }
  def delete(entity: E): Future[Int] = db.run(entities.filter(_.id === entity.id).delete)
  def find(id: Int): Future[E] = db.run(entities.filter(_.id === entities.id))

  trait BaseTable { this: Table[_] =>
    def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  }
}
```

Could somebody please point me to my mistakes? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Database agnostic and Code is highly reusable**

***I am using `Slick` with `Playframework` and this is how I achieved database agnostic and generic repository.***

***Note that this work is inspired from Active Slick***

*I want to have basic crud operations like this to be defined on my `case class`. I should be able to do `count`, `update`, `delete` and `create`. I want to write the curd code just once and reuse it for ever.*

Here is the snippet which demonstrates this.

```
case class Dog(name: String, id: Option[Long] = None)
Dog("some_dog").save()
Dog("some_dog").insert()
Dog("some_dog", Some(1)).delete()
```

*CrudActions.scala*

```
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext


trait CrudActions {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  type Model

  def count: DBIO[Int]

  def save(model: Model)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Model]

  def update(model: Model)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Model]

  def delete(model: Model)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int]

  def fetchAll(fetchSize: Int = 100)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): StreamingDBIO[Seq[Model], Model]
}
```

*Now lets get our `Entity` into picture. Note that `Entity` is nothing but our case class*

*`Entity` is `case class` on which we do crud operations. For locating our entity lets also have `Id` in place. `Id` is important for locating and operating an entity or record in the database. Also `Id` uniquely identities for entity*

*EntityActionsLike.scala*

```
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait EntityActionsLike extends CrudActions {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  type Entity

  type Id

  type Model = Entity

  def insert(entity: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Id]

  def deleteById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int]

  def findById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity]

  def findOptionById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Option[Entity]]
}
```

import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

*Now lets implement these methods. For doing operations we need `Table` and `TableQuery`. Lets say we have `table` and `tableQuery`. The good about traits is we can declare a contract and leave the implementation details to subclasses or subtypes*

*EntityActions.scala*

```
trait EntityActions extends EntityActionsLike {
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  type EntityTable <: Table[Entity]

  def tableQuery: TableQuery[EntityTable]

  def $id(table: EntityTable): Rep[Id]

  def modelIdContract: ModelIdContract[Entity,Id]

  override def count: DBIO[Int] = tableQuery.size.result

  override def insert(entity: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Id] = {
    tableQuery.returning(tableQuery.map($id(_))) += entity
  }

  override def deleteById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int] = {
    filterById(id).delete
  }

  override def findById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity] = {
    filterById(id).result.head
  }

  override def findOptionById(id: Id)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Option[Entity]] = {
    filterById(id).result.headOption
  }

  override def save(model: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity] = {
    insert(model).flatMap { id =>
      filterById(id).result.head
    }.transactionally
  }

  override def update(model: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Entity] = {
    filterById(modelIdContract.get(model)).update(model).map { _ => model }.transactionally
  }

  override def delete(model: Entity)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int] = {
    filterById(modelIdContract.get(model)).delete
  }

  override def fetchAll(fetchSize: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): StreamingDBIO[Seq[Entity], Entity] = {
    tableQuery.result.transactionally.withStatementParameters(fetchSize = fetchSize)
  }

  def filterById(id: Id) = tableQuery.filter($id(_) === id)

  def baseTypedType: BaseTypedType[Id]

  protected implicit lazy val btt: BaseTypedType[Id] = baseTypedType

}
```

*ActiveRecord.scala*

```
import slick.dbio.DBIO

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext


abstract class ActiveRecord[R <: CrudActions](val repo: R) {
  def model: repo.Model
  def save()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[repo.Model] = repo.save(model)
  def update()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[repo.Model] = repo.update(model)
  def delete()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Int] = repo.delete(model)
}
```

*ModelContract.scala*

```
case class ModelIdContract[A, B](get: A => B, set: (A, B) => A)
```

**How to Use**

*Sample.scala*

```
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.{ActiveRecord, EntityActions, ModelIdContract}

case class Dog(name: String, id: Option[Long] = None)

@Singleton
class DogActiveRecord @Inject() (databaseConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends EntityActions {

  override val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = databaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]

  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  override def tableQuery = TableQuery(new Dogs(_))

  override def $id(table: Dogs): Rep[Id] = table.id

  override def modelIdContract: ModelIdContract[Dog, Id] = ModelIdContract(dog => dog.id.get, (dog, id) => dog.copy(id = Some(id)))

  override def baseTypedType: BaseTypedType[Id] = implicitly[BaseTypedType[Id]]

  override type Entity = Dog
  override type Id = Long
  override type EntityTable = Dogs

  class Dogs(tag: Tag) extends Table[Dog](tag, "DogsTable") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def * = (name, id.?) <> (Dog.tupled, Dog.unapply)
  }

  implicit class ActiveRecordImplicit(val model: Entity) extends ActiveRecord(this)

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val result = Dog("some_dog").save()

  val res2 = Dog("some_other_dog", Some(1)).delete()

  val res3 = Dog("some_crazy_dog", Some(1)).update()
}
```

Now we can do operations on `Dog` directly like this

```
Dog("some_dog").save()
```

*This implicit does the magic for us*

```
implicit class ActiveRecordImplicit(val model: Entity) extends ActiveRecord(this)
```

*You can also add `scheme` creation and dropping logic in EntityActions*

```
tableQuery.schema.create
table.schema.drop
```

Comment: That is VERY interesting and exhaustive answer! Though I changed a lot from your solution, I inherited from it a lot as well. Thank you!

Comment: @mr.nothing  you can accept the solution if you think it serves the purpose.